# Dynamic DropDownList index event does not trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

In an ASP.Net application, I have a page where the user can purchase items. In order to that, they use two DropDownLists : one to find their itemID, and second one to pick the amount of items they want to buy, named Amount and PurchasedItemIDs. Each item has a seperate Herbs / Gems price.

I want to change a Label, called TotalPrice to calucate the total price of both herbs and gems whenever the user changes the index selected.

I've made an event:

```
protected void Price_Changed_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int HerbPrice = -1;
        int GemPrice = -1;
        int AmountPurchased = int.Parse(Amount.SelectedValue);
        //Code to get the price out of the items. If it's relevant, ask for it.
        foreach (shopItem t in Items)
        {
            if (t.ID == int.Parse(PurchaseItemIDs.SelectedValue))
            {
                HerbPrice = t.herbCost*AmountPurchased;
                GemPrice = t.gemCost * AmountPurchased;
            }
        }
        if (HerbPrice == -1 || GemPrice == -1)
            throw new Exception("ItemID not found.");
        else
            TotalPrice.Text = "Herbs: "+ HerbPrice + ", Gems: " + GemPrice; 
    }
```

And I editted the dropdownlists:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="PurchaseItemIDs" runat="server" Width="120px" 
    BackColor="#F6F1DB" ForeColor="#7d6754" Font-Names="Andalus" CssClass="ddl" 
    onselectedindexchanged="Price_Changed_Event" 
    ontextchanged="Price_Changed_Event">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Amount" runat="server" Width="120px" BackColor="#F6F1DB" 
    ForeColor="#7d6754" Font-Names="Andalus" CssClass="ddl" 
    onselectedindexchanged="Price_Changed_Event" 
    ontextchanged="Price_Changed_Event">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Despite this, when I change the amount of the items I want to buy, the label's text does not change at all from the default. I set a breakpoint by the start of the event - it is not triggered.

**EDIT**:
Page load content:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    ListItem t = new ListItem();
                    t.Value = "" + i;
                    t.Text = "" + i;
                    Amount.Items.Add(t);
                }
                foreach (int id in from item in getItemsForUser(((User)Session["User"]).Username) select item.ID)
                {
                    ListItem itm = new ListItem();
                    itm.Text = "" + id;
                    itm.Value = "" + id;
                    PurchaseItemIDs.Items.Add(itm);
                }
                TotalPrice.Text = "Pick an item and an amount to see the price.";
            }
             //irrelevant stuff.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can I see your Page_Load code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add AutoPostBack="true" to your dropdownlist controls:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="PurchaseItemIDs" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" Width="120px" 
BackColor="#F6F1DB" ForeColor="#7d6754" Font-Names="Andalus" CssClass="ddl" 
onselectedindexchanged="Price_Changed_Event" 
ontextchanged="Price_Changed_Event">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="Amount" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="120px" BackColor="#F6F1DB" 
ForeColor="#7d6754" Font-Names="Andalus" CssClass="ddl" 
onselectedindexchanged="Price_Changed_Event" 
ontextchanged="Price_Changed_Event">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I've changed the code to fit this (editted the question) - yet I get the same error.

Comment: It does not even get into the event, Let alone execute the first foreach. The first line is an integer declaration - `int HerbPrice = -1;`. I set a breakpoint there, and it is not triggered, regardless of what I do :/